# Cloudera Management Service Actions не запускается

Tags: cloudera

Ошибка, которая вылетает, если нажать кнопку "start":

```
Command failed to run because service Cloudera Management Service has invalid configuration. Review and correct its configuration. First error: Service mgmt has 0 Reports Managers. Cloudera Management Service requires at least 1 Reports Manager.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]